# Obtaining the primary key identifier value for a record (SQL)

Tags: sql, android-studio, primary-key

I have been working on a school project- an app. I've been using an sql db for my database.
For one particular task, I wanted to use the customer's username (which is unique) to find the corresponding customer_id value (an auto increment integer primary key) for other purposes.
The code I used looked like this:

```
public int getCustomerid(String username){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor resultset = db.rawQuery("SELECT cust_code FROM Customer where username='" + username+ "'", null);
        resultset.moveToFirst();
        return resultset.getInt(0);
    }
```

I have used this format of queries for obtaining other values like password, email id, etc. However, when I try to use this method to extract the primary key value, I get a null pointer exception error.
Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks,

Comment: Learn to use parameters!  Don't munge query strings with constant values.  This is particularly important if you are learning SQL.  You want to learn the safe way to write applications.

Comment: It would be useful if you add the exception

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm sorry, but could you elaborate on your explanation? Our teachers don't give us any learning material for these projects, so I pick up a few methods and structures here and there from different articles/videos.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why this works:

public int getCustomerid(String username){

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String SQLquery = "SELECT cust_code FROM Customer where username='" + username+ "'"
    Cursor resultset = db.rawQuery(SQLquery, null);
    resultset.moveToFirst();
    return resultset.getInt(0);
}
```

I now see how creating parameters adds more clarity. Thank you very much Mr. Gordon Linoff.